# How do I get specific values from a lua table?

Tags: lua

I have a local that prints `{"text1":value1, "text2":value2, "text3":value3}`.

The local is from an export that returns a table, so I used `json.encode` to get the table, but I don't know where to go from here. How would I get the values inside the brackets seperately?

Comment: `d=json.decode('{"text1":"value1", "text2":"value2", "text3":"value3"}'); print(d.text1)`

Comment: Can't you just *not* use `json.encode` and index the table directly or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`d=json.decode('{"text1":"value1", "text2":"value2", "text3":"value3"}'); print(d.text1)`

Solved by @Egor Skriptunoff